# A detailed explanation of the new light-in-4D-with-quantum-Hall-effect experiments?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, quantum-hall-effect

I have read several recent articles regarding the two experiments that were done that reveal the effects of a fourth spatial dimension via the quantum Hall effect using lasers and whatnot. I found these articles unsatisfactory and didn't really understand what the quantum Hall effect was or exactly how the experiment worked and what it showed.

Could someone give a thorough explanation of the experiments and the quantum mechanics/theoretical framework behind them, without shying away from the complexities?

Comment: Please provide the links to the articles you mention

Comment: @YuriyS There were a ton of terrible articles about it a few days ago. I was also wondering what the actual discovery was.  Sounds like they just ran a simulation? https://www.express.co.uk/news/science/901542/science-USA-Europe-science-fourth-dimension-news-latest-breakthrough-quantum-physics https://www.techworm.net/2018/01/scientists-prove-existence-fourth-spatial-dimension.html http://www.newsweek.com/what-time-fourth-dimension-experiments-lasers-lights-772061

Comment: @endolith, your second link has two papers from Nature linked, which are both open-access. You can see that the research is experimental, though it of course has nothing to do with 4th space dimension at all

Comment: @YuriyS Third link, and here are direct links: https://www.nature.com/articles/nature25000.epdf https://www.nature.com/articles/nature25011.epdf  But having access to the papers doesn't mean I understand them.

Comment: @endolith, my mistake, the third link. Of course, I don't understand the topic either, but it's quite clear both are experimental

Answer (score -2):

I know well the quantum Hall effect which is a two dimensional effect. What these people possibly found is at most two multiplied 2D QHE which looks like a 4D effect. There is no way to find a 4D effect with 4 degrees of freedom. The 4D that these people imagine to see in their effects are dependent dimensions.

F.G.

Comment: I asked for a detailed explanation. This isn't better than the articles.

Comment: @QFTUNIverse, I suggest you look up the original scientific papers linked here: http://www.newsweek.com/what-time-fourth-dimension-experiments-lasers-lights-772061. The physics is quite complicated, I don't think I can explain it myself. Unfortunately, the corresponding author's email is not listed, but you could try googling them to find a valid email and ask them for an explanation. Most scientists are happy to talk about their research especially in relation to a "sensationalist" news publications such as this